# CSS media query for positioning logo at centre for mobile devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I think this is fairly simple for CSS experts but I am a newbie to CSS and media queries. Please help me.

I have mat-toolbar with menu button and app logo onto into, following HTML code describes,

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <mat-toolbar style="background-color: black;">
    <div class="logo">
          <img src="/assets/images/Cycle.ico"/>
          <span style="color: orange;">CYC <span style="color: white;">Admin</span></span>
    </div>
    <button class="menuButton" mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()"><mat-icon>menu</mat-icon></button>
    </mat-toolbar>
```

When I viewed through mobile devices, the logo should display at centre of toolbar and menu button to the left.

How can I make it possible through CSS media query?
Please help me.

Here is the Stackblitz I have tried :  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrdqir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the CSS you need to add to make it happen.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.toolbar {
  text-align: center;
}
.toolbar .logo {
  width: 100%;
}
.toolbar .menuButton {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 8px;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped me, How can i reduce the icon size in mobile window?

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Comment: To reduce icon size you need to specify `height` or `width` to `.toolbar .logo img {}`. And about explaining my answer, I set 100% width to the `logo` element and assigned `position: absolute` to `menuButton` to pull it to the left edge.

Comment: Thanks , it got working, I have one more doubt, What should I do, if I want to add 3 dots onto toolbar when it is mobile device and normal when it is in desktop? Please help me

Comment: You need to have 2 icons and show one in mobile and next in large screens. Try this code.
<mat-icon><span class="hidden-xs">menu</span><span class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">more_vert</span></mat-icon>